# fetch first daily row using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

i have a table called sans that stores event information with columns for id, date, and hour. 
 I'm trying to write a query using Eloquent to fetch the first event of each day. My current code works fine for today's events, but I'm having trouble modifying it to fetch the first event for each day beyond today.
Can you help me with this?

my current code:

```
$sans=sans::where('id',$id)
->where('user_id',$user->id)
->whereDate('date','>=',date('Y-m-d'))
->where('Hour','>=',date('H:i'))
->first();
```

but its work correct just for today's sans

Comment: And what should it do otherwise? You wrote some condition that checks the date to be at least today and the current time of day to be at least the current one (so while checking it on 2018-07-17 23:00, you will not receive any rows from future dates where the hour is before 11pm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can concate date and time use where condition & you can use DATE_FORMAT() [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

```
$sans=sans::where('id',$id)
         ->where('user_id',$user->id)
        ->where(DB::Raw("CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d'),' ',hour)"),'>=',date('Y-m-d H:i'))
         ->orderBy('date','DESC')
         ->first();
```

Comment: i looking for a code seams like CONCAT(date," ",hour) but this can't compere date because returned it:
2018-07-15 00:00:00 18:58

Comment: @MahdiMirhendi plz check answer now